# No readline support detected. Windows Console (PowerShell)

Tags: php, windows, консоль, powershell, magento

Здравствуйте, ну если объяснить что я пытаюсь сделать то вот:
Есть **Interactiv Magento Console**, я его установил и при попытке вызова файла выводится следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в итоге код выполняется, но из за того, что выводится сообщение про то, что no readline suppor detected я не могу (как мне кажется) воспользоваться **Interactiv Magento Console**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения нету) Оказалось, что этот файл не будет работать в Windows так как функция pcntl_signal() не скомпилирована для php под Windows.